# Angular 2 searchtext

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have a dropdown menu with a search function and a list with projects (and checkboxes) I would like to make the searchterm update the projects in that list.

example:

I have 5 projects:
 - project1
 - potato
 - listItem1
 - listItem2
 - whatever

The idea is when you didn't type anything you see all 5 items, and if you type "p" you would only see project1 and potato. This is my code so far:

```
<div id="dropdown-menu">
    <button id="show-users" (click)="showMenu = !showMenu">Project toevoegen</button> 
    <div id="drp-project-select">
        <div class="scroller" [hidden]="!showMenu">
            <div id="search-wrapper">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                <input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op naam..." >
            </div>   
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="#project of projectdata.LoginResponse?.ProjectVM, #i = index">
                    <label class="checkbox-label" >
                        <input type="checkbox" class="dropdown-checkbox" [(ngModel)]="project.isChecked" >
                        <span>{{project.Project}}</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a filter pipe. 
For a full example see https://plnkr.co/edit/4Il8QMlh9UYQ4hyrnU3W?p=preview

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op naam..." #search>
...
<li *ngFor="#project of projectdata.LoginResponse?.ProjectVM | filter:'Project':search.value, #i = index">
```

Supports only to filter by one column, but shouldn't be to hard to extend.
It returns the same result if there were no changes to prevent

> EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core'

@Pipe({name: 'filter'})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  previousResult:any[];

  transform(value:any[], args:string[]) : any {
    if(!value || !args || args.length < 2 || !args[0] || !args[1]) {
      return value;
    }
    console.log('value: ' + value);
    console.log('args: ' + args);

    var result = value.filter((val) => {
      console.log('item: ' + val[args[0]])
      var contains = val[args[0]].indexOf(args[1]) > -1;
      console.log('found: ' + contains);
      return contains;
    });

    console.log(result);
    if(this.previousResult && this.previousResult.length == result.length) {
      for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if(this.previousResult[i] != result[i]) {
          console.log(i);
          this.previousResult = result;
          return this.previousResult;
        }
      }
    }
    this.previousResult = result;
    return this.previousResult;
  }
}
```

Comment: Günter, I'm absolutely positive that the searchpipe works as it should. The only problem is that user is an object:
export interface User {
 Id: number;
 Name: string;
 UserName: string;
 CreationDate: Date;
 ContractHrs: number;
 HoursFullDay: number;
 HoursHalfDay: number;
 MaxMoreHours: number;
 WarnMoreHours: number;
}

I have tried to work it out myself by adding this:
<li *ngFor="#user of projectdata.LoginResponse?.UserVM | searchpipe:'user.Name':search.value, #i = index">
I renamed the pipe to searchpipe for code clarity.

Comment: Your question didn't contain any information about that. I guess you can figure out the rest anyway.

Comment: The mayor problem is that project.Name does not get found. I tried using the elvis operator(again) and that doesn't seem to fix the error I get.

EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in [projectdata.LoginResponse?.UserVM | searchpipe:'user?.Name':search.value in DropDownUsers@15:20]

the value keeps being an object object:
value: [object Object],[object Object]

and most importantly the item is undefined:
item: undefined

Comment: You could extend my plunker to demonstrate what's actually going on. It's hard to reason about your problem from just a few comments.

Comment: As I was importing the interface to your Plunker I found out that I did a terrible thing. I changed your code from searchpipe:'Project' to searchpipe:'project'. That is the reason why it did not work as it was supposed to. I try to avoid copy/paste to make sure I understand code instead of just pasting so it works. Typo's tend to crawl in then...

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage a form control to do that:

```
constructor() {
  this.ctrl = new Control();

  // Some data for testing  
  this.showMenu = true;
  this.projectdata = {
    LoginResponse: {
      ProjectVM: [{
        isChecked: true,
        Project: 'test'
      }]
    }
  };

  this.initialData = this.projectdata.LoginResponse.ProjectVM
  this.filteredData = this.initialData.slice(0, 5);

  this.ctrl.valueChanges.subscribe(
    (val) => {
      if (!val) {
        this.filteredData = this.initialData.slice(0, 5);
      }
      this.filteredData = this.initialData.filter((project) => {
        return new RegExp('^'+val).test(project.Project);
      });
    });
  }
```

Don't forget to reference the control on your input:

```
<input [ngFormControl]="ctrl" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op naam..." >
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ocgXxAvcPPtvW5SXEDQ9?p=preview.